# Include T4 generated c# class in the build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, t4

I have a runtime T4 template using which i generate a .cs file . I need to access this generated file in my code . I dont see the generated class file so that i could use it but if i do a "Show all files " and then include it in my solution and build i am then able to access the generated file.

How do i use this generated c# file without having to do any changed manually  .

It should be something like I use the code

```
RuntimeTextTemplate runTimeGen = new RuntimeTextTemplate();
File.WriteAllText("RuntimeGenerator3.cs", runTimeGen.TransformText());
```

right after the last statement i should be able to access the generated class ?
Is the template file . I am using a console application.

The name of the runtime template is **RuntimeGenerator.tt**

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

namespace Controls
{
    public class DropDownControlUtility
    {
        public static string ForeColor
        {
            get
            {
                return "Blue";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

class with the Main method contains code below

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RuntimeGenerator gen = new RuntimeGenerator();
            File.WriteAllText("DropDownUtility.cs", gen.TransformText());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your template and how do you generate the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 different templates [Run-time text template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) and [Design-time text template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd820620.aspx). Files generated with design-time template are included in the project automatically. Run-time text template are used to generate files in run-time when you launch your program, while design-time text templates  let you generate program code and other files in your Visual Studio project.

So all you need is to create new design-time template (TextTemplate) and put your code in it. 
To generate the file: In Solution Explorer, on the shortcut menu of any file, choose Run Custom Tool or click Transform All Templates in the Build menu. You also can setup your project to generate files [automaically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd820620.aspx#Regenerating).